# How to use functions between classes in python

Tags: python

If I have more than one class in a python script, how do I call a function from the first class in the second class?

Here is an Example:

```
Class class1():

  def function1():
        blah blah blah

Class class2():

 *How do I call function1 to here from class1*
```

Comment: If you really need the functionality int class2 from class1 it would make more sense to put it into class2 instead, but I realize that this isn't part of your question but rather more some information.

Comment: I need the function in both classes

Comment: A more concrete example would help clarify your intention.

Comment: Ah, in that case in my opinion it would make more sense to not put the function in either class but have it on its own.

Comment: Questions like this reflect a fundamental misunderstanding. Classes **are not** simply containers for functions; they're blueprints for objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in classes are also known as methods, and they are invoked on objects.  The way to call a method in class1 from class2 is to have an instance of class1:

```
class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c1 = Class1()
        self.c1.function1()
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is probably through inheritance:

```
class Base(object):
    def function1(self):
        # blah blah blah

class Class1(Base):
    def a_method(self):
        self.function1()  # works

class Class2(Base):
    def some_method(self):
        self.function1()  # works

c1 = Class1()
c1.function1()  # works
c2 = Class2()
c2.function1()  # works
```

Comment: i think you mean `c2.function1()`